# Does Google Speech To Text comply with RFC 6787

Tags: speech-recognition, unimrcp

More generally, are there ASR open standards that we can expect vendors to comply with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fields develops very quickly, so it is too early for standards. If you want to use google asr with mrcp protocol, there are servers like Unimrcp which have google backend, not fully free though

http://unimrcp.org/solutions/google-speech-recognition

overall, unimrcp is somewhat outdated protocol as all other standartized things. If you want to provide best experience, you'd better use google api directly to enjoy all the features like streaming, speaker identification and multilanguage recognition.